# Using different multiple regression models that each change the available data

Tags: multiple-regression, missing-data, small-sample

So I'm trying to analyse the difference in taxes paid between listed and unlisted companies.
However, the sample consists of around 6000 unlisted and only 70 listed companies (there are only 210 in the population).

Now, due to limited availability of data entries, quite a few listed companies have to be eliminated from the analysis. My lackluster procedure and data availability are currently as follows:

1.Simple regression model (6000 VS 70 listed)
2.Multiple regression model (5000 VS 32 listed due to adding a variable that requires information, which is missing for some companies).
3.Multiple regression model (3000 VS 12 listed)

My question is this: How can I still draw statistically significant conclusions from limited observations? As in, only 20 out of 210 listed companies have the required information I need for my model.

Answer (score 1):

First I would advise against seeking statistical significance. Practical significance is much more important.

One approach you can take is to utilise multiple imputation, which under conditions where the missingness is related to observed variables (or is completely random) can result in unbiased and more precise estimates.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.